# Image downsizing script creates image of bigger size in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, wallpaper

I have the following script named wallpaperise.sh that takes an image and converts it to the the same own only this time with 16:9 resolution.

```
## Usage: ./wallpaperise.sh <imagename.jpg>

aw=16   #desired aspect ratio width...
ah=9    #and height

in="$1"
out="wallpaperised_$1"

wid=`convert "$in" -format "%[w]" info:`
hei=`convert "$in" -format "%[h]" info:`

tarar=`echo $aw/$ah | bc -l`
imgar=`convert "$in" -format "%[fx:w/h]" info:`

if (( $(bc <<< "$tarar > $imgar") ))
then
  nhei=`echo $wid/$tarar | bc`
  convert "$in" -gravity center -crop ${wid}x${nhei}+0+0 "$out"
elif (( $(bc <<< "$tarar < $imgar") ))
then
  nwid=`echo $hei*$tarar | bc`
  convert "$in" -gravity center -crop ${nwid}x${hei}+0+0 "$out"
else
  cp "$in" "$out"
fi
```

The problem is that the image it creates ( **even if it doesn't change the image at all** ) is of a bigger file size than the original?

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting JPEG with ImageMagick's convert, you can choose your own file size with `-quality 1` (tiny) to `-quality 100` (huge).

As the flag name suggests, the file size is directly correlated to the image quality.

If you don't specify one, [ImageMagick's documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) says it will try to guess the input's quality level, or default to 92 if it can't. In your case, it's conservatively choosing a higher quality setting and resulting in a larger file.

You can try e.g. `-quality 80`, see how it looks, and increase or decrease as you see fit.